# how to trigger re-render of rating component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying out React for first time. I have taken a problem to try building a 5-star rating component. It prints all logs properly. Just that the component is not re-rendering when state is changed. Appreciate your time reading this. Here is [JSFiddle version of the problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/tusar/4m6e23kL/37/)

HTML:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

CSS:

```
span {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size:25px;
}

span.active {
  color:red;
}
```

JS:

```
class RatingApp extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {
        rating : 0,
        items: [
            {id:1, active: false },
            {id:2, active: false },
            {id:3, active: false },
            {id:4, active: false },
            {id:5, active: false }
        ]
    }
}

toggleClass(itemId) {

    console.log("itemId ----" + itemId);

    var changedItems = this.state.items;
    console.log("id ----" + changedItems[itemId-1].id);
    console.log("active ----" + changedItems[itemId-1].active);
    console.log("pre changedItems ---- " + changedItems);
    for(var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        if(i<=itemId) {
            changedItems[i-1].active = true;
            console.log("active class added");
        }
        else {
            changedItems[i-1].active = false;
        }
    }
    console.log("post changedItems ---- " + changedItems);
    this.setState=({
        rating: itemId,
        items: changedItems
    });
};

render() {
    return (
      <div id="rating">
   
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
        <span key={item.id} className={item.active ? "active" : ""}
            onClick={() => this.toggleClass(item.id)} 
        >
           *
        </span>
        ))}
     
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<RatingApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: `this.setState=(` should be `this.setState(`. `this.setState` is a function you should call, not a property to assign to.

Comment: Thank you @FelixKling sir ! That is working. I shall accept your solution if you kindly put this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## remove the = after this.setState

The first issue is this part

```
this.setState=({
        rating: itemId,
        items: changedItems
    });
```

it should be

```
this.setState({
        rating: itemId,
        items: changedItems
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in

this.setState=({
rating: itemId,
items: changedItems
})

change it to this.setState({
rating: itemId,
items: changedItems
})

Refer below

```js
class RatingApp extends React.Component {
    
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
        
    this.state = {
        rating : 0,
        items: [
        {id:1, active: false },
        {id:2, active: false },
        {id:3, active: false },
        {id:4, active: false },
        {id:5, active: false }
      ]
    }
  }
  
  toggleClass(itemId) {
  
    console.log("itemId ----" + itemId);
    
    var changedItems = this.state.items;
    console.log("id ----" + changedItems[itemId-1].id);
    console.log("active ----" + changedItems[itemId-1].active);
    console.log("pre changedItems ---- " + changedItems);
    for(var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        if(i<=itemId) {
            changedItems[i-1].active = true;
        console.log("active class added");
      }
      else {
        changedItems[i-1].active = false;
      }
    }
    console.log("post changedItems ---- " + changedItems);
    
  /*   
  this.setState=({
        rating: itemId,
        items: changedItems
    }); */
    this.setState({
        rating: itemId,
        items: changedItems
    });
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="rating">
       
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
          <span key={item.id} className={item.active ? "active" : ""}
            onClick={() => this.toggleClass(item.id)} 
          >
           *
          </span>
        ))}
       
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<RatingApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
span {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size:25px;
}

span.active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

  


 

</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```